# Type Deconstruction

Tags: haskell, types, type-constructor

My data types will always have at least two parameters, and the last two parameters are always 'q' and 'm', respectively:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances, TypeOperators, DataKinds, ConstraintKinds, FlexibleInstances #-}

data D1 q m = D1 q
data D2 t q m = D2 q

class Foo a where -- a has kind * -> *
   f :: a x -> a x

class (Foo b) => Bar b where -- b has kind * -> *
   -- the purpose of g is to change ONE type parameter, while fixing the rest
   -- the intent of the equality constraints is to decompose the parameter b into
   -- its base type and 'q' parameter, then use the same base type with a *different*
   -- `q` parameter for the answer
   g :: (b ~ bBase q1, b' ~ bBase q2) => b m -> b' m

instance (Foo (D2 t q), Integral q) => Bar (D2 t q) where
   g (D2 q) = D2 $ fromIntegral q -- LINE 1
```

This program results in the error

```
Could not deduce (bBase ~ D2 t0) (LINE 1)
```

When I wrote the instance, I certainly intended `bBase ~ D2 t`. I guess t is not bound somehow (hence the introduction of t0), and I don't know if GHC can deconstruct this type at all. Or maybe I'm just doing something silly.

More to the point, this kind of type equality/type deconstruction wouldn't be necessary if I make the parameter to Bar have kind * -> * -> *. But then I couldn't enforce the Foo constraint:

```
class (Foo (b q)) => Bar b where -- b has kind * -> * -> *
  g :: b q m -> q b' -- this signature is now quite simple, and I would have no problem implementing it
```

This won't work because q is not a parameter to Bar, and I don't *want* it to a parameter to Bar.

I found a solution using TWO extra "dummy" associated types, but I don't really like having them around if I don't need them:

```
class (Foo b, b ~ (BBase b) (BMod b)) => Bar b where -- b has kind * -> *
  type BBase b :: * -> * -> *
  type BMod b :: *

  g :: (Qux (BMod b), Qux q') => b m -> (BBase b) q' m

instance (Foo (D2 t q), Integral q) => Bar (D2 t q) where
  type BBase (D2 t q) = D2 t
  type BMod (D2 t q) = q

  g (D2 q) = D2 $ fromIntegral q
```

This works, but it amounts to explicitly deconstructing the type, which I think should be unnecessary given the simple type of the instance.

I'm looking for a solution to either approach: either tell me how I can enforce a class constraint on a "more-applied" type, or tell me how to make GHC deconstruct types.

Thanks!

Comment: The full error message I get is `amy16.hs:7:1:
    Illegal equational constraint b ~ bBase q1
    (Use -XGADTs or -XTypeFamilies to permit this)
    When checking the class method:
      g :: forall (bBase :: * -> * -> *) q1 (b' :: * -> *) q2 m.
           (b ~ bBase q1, b' ~ bBase q2) =>
           b m -> b' m
    In the class declaration for `Bar'
Failed, modules loaded: none.` So I think you need to add either the `GADTs` language pragma or the `TypeFamilies` pragma, and possibly some other pragmas as well.

Comment: I didn't include the compile flags/language pragmas in the code above, but of course I'm using everything I need in those terms (which should make all of the snippets work): TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances, TypeOperators, DataKinds, ConstraintKinds, FlexibleInstances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe, you have types `b' :: * -> * -> *` for which you wish to constrain the applied `b' t :: * -> *` (for all `t`).

As you summise, you either need to deconstruct a type, which is your attempt here
starting from a `b :: * -> *` assumed to be the result of a type
application `b = b' t`, or to enforce a constraint on a "more-applied" type, instead 
from the start-point of a `b' :: * -> * -> *`.

Deconstructing a type is not possible, since the compiler does not know if `b` is even "deconstructable". Indeed, it may not be, e.g., I can make an instance `instance Bar Maybe`, but `Maybe` cannot be deconstructed into a type `b' :: * -> * -> *` and some type `t :: *`.

Starting instead from a type `b' :: * -> * -> *`, the constraints on an application of `b'` can be moved into the body of the class, where the variables are quantified:

```
  class Bar (b :: * -> * -> *) where
      g :: (Foo (b q1), Foo (b q2)) => b q1 m -> b q2 m
```

For your example there is one further wrinkle: q1 and q2 may have their own constraints,
e.g. for the `D2` instance you require the `Integral` constraint. However, `Bar` fixes the constraints on `q1` and `q2` for all instances (in this case the empty constraint). A solution is to use "constraint-kinded type families" which allow instances to specify their own constraints:

```
  class Bar (b :: * -> * -> *) where
      type Constr b t :: Constraint
      g :: (Foo (b q1), Foo (b q2), Constr b q1, Constr b q2) => b q1 m -> b q2 m
```

(include `{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}` and import `GHC.Prim`)

Then you can write your `D2` instance:

```
   instance Bar (D2 t) where
      type Constr (D2 t) q = Integral q
      g (D2 q) = D2 $ fromIntegral q
```