# Pattern Matching on Promoted Types

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, higher-kinded-types, type-kinds

We can write single, comprehensive instances for parameters of kind `*`:

```
class MyClass d where
    f :: d -> Int

instance MyClass (Maybe d) where  
    f _ = 3

test1 :: Maybe d -> Int
test1 x = f x
```

This compiles just fine, and note that we do NOT need a (MyClass (Maybe d)) constraint on test1 because the compiler finds a matching instance for any `Maybe d`.

We can even write an all-encompassing instance for class parameters that are type constructors:

```
class MyClass2 (a :: * -> *) where
    g :: Tagged (a Int) Int

instance MyClass2 a where
    g = Tagged 3

test2 :: Int
test2 = untag (g :: Tagged (Maybe Int) Int)
```

This also compiles fine, and test2 does not need a (MyClass2 Maybe) constraint, because the compiler finds a matching instance.

Consider the following toy code to compute the length of a (promoted) type list:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators,
DataKinds,
KindSignatures,
GADTs,
FlexibleInstances,
FlexibleContexts,
ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Tagged
import Data.Proxy

data HList :: [*] -> * where
              HNil :: HList '[]
              HCons :: a -> HList as -> HList (a ': as)

class ListLen a where
    len :: Tagged a Int

instance ListLen (HList '[]) where
    len = Tagged 0

instance (ListLen (HList as)) => ListLen (HList (a ': as)) where
    len = Tagged (1+(untag (len :: Tagged (HList as) Int)))

test3 :: Int
test3 = untag (len :: Tagged (HList '[Int, Double, Integer]) Int)

test4 :: (Proxy (HList qs)) -> Int
test4 (_ :: Proxy (HList qs)) = untag (len :: Tagged (HList qs) Int) -- error occurs here
```

This results in the error:

```
No instance for (ListLen (HList qs))
      arising from a use of `len'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (ListLen (HList qs))
    ...
```

If we comment out the signature for `test4`, GHCi infers the type as

```
test4 :: (ListLen (HList qs)) => (Proxy (HList qs)) -> Int
```

*but this shouldn't be necessary*. Clearly, I've written instances for `ListLen` that match any conceivable type list: an 'empty list' case, and a 'cons' case. The problem remains the same if I change the kind of the `ListLen` parameter to have kind `[*]` (i.e., remove the `HList` wrapper in `ListLen` and its instances).

If we comment out `test4`, `test3` compiles and runs fine: since I (essentially) gave it explicit syntax (`'[Int,Double,Integer]`) for how I constructed the type list, the compiler was able to find matching instances.

I'm attempting to write code that builds a type list for me, so I will not have to write out the explicit type list syntax. However, it seems that using explicit syntax is the only way GHC is able to match these comprehensive instances. Perhaps there's a case I'm missing? Syntax I'm not using?

*What can I do to make GHC realize that I have an instance for everything of kind `[*]`?*
I'm using GHC 7.4.2. This *might* be related to a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273085/type-deconstruction) about deconstructing non-promoted types. *THE* paper on type promotion can be found [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/.../fc-kind-poly.pdf).

Comment: Title suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You have *different* instances, how would it no which one?  GHC has to pick the instance, and that is a non-parametric operation, so requires a constraint.  I don't think what you want to do makes sense.

Comment: GHC can even resolve *overlapping* instances (which these aren't) at runtime by using an explicit class constraint (that would otherwise be inferred). Why can't it see that there is *always* a match, even if it has to wait until runtime to pick the appropriate instance? Of course, I'm asking it to do this *without* the explicit (and gratuitous) class constraint, which I don't have the luxury of providing.

Comment: @Eric, all instances are chosen at compile time or passed in as parameters generated from constraints.  Nothing is resolved at runtime.

Comment: @Eric: because the instances do different things.  The point in *non parametricity* always requires a constraint.  Ad hoc polymorphism is ad hoc.

Comment: Try thinking about it in terms of the dictionary translation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not exactly what you want, but gets pretty close.  I started out with

```
data Proxy a where
  Proxy :: ListLen a => Proxy
```

then

```
data Proxy a where
  Proxy :: Tagged a Int -> Proxy a
```

resulting in

```
test4 :: (Proxy (HList qs)) -> Int
test4 (Proxy len) = untag len
```

The problem is you either need to have the constraint, or have `Proxy` contain evidence of the required class (even though instances exist for all available kinds).  Here, the class method is just included in `Proxy`.

A completely different option is to just not use a type class at all, and implement `len` in the usual way (transcribed from `Data.List.length`).

```
len :: HList a -> Int
len l = len' l 0
  where
    len' :: HList a -> Int -> Int
    len' HNil a = a
    len' (HCons _ xs) a = len' xs $! a + 1
```